Azure : Remove read/write access to a resource for contributors
Is it possible to remove read/write access to a resource for contributors on Azure ?
We are not using Azure Bastion anymore, we want to disable access to VMs via Azure Bastion for contributors BUT we don't want to delete it completely since we will keep it if we have an emergency (eg : our other Bastion provider is down).
I used Deployment Stack to deploy a deny assignment rule but as you can see in this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/stack/group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-stack-group-create
deny-settings-mode can only be set to denyDelete, denyWriteAndDelete, none but not read.

Yes, it is possible to remove read/write access to a resource for contributors on Azure. One way to achieve this is by using Azure role-based access control (RBAC) to assign a custom role that only grants the necessary permissions. You can create a custom role that only allows read access to the resource, and then assign that role to the contributors. This way, they will not be able to write to the resource.

Another way to achieve this is by using deny assignments, which attach a set of deny actions to a user, group, or service principal at a particular scope to deny access. You can use deployment stacks to deploy a deny assignment rule, but as you mentioned, the deny-settings-mode parameter only allows denyDelete, denyWriteAndDelete, and none. However, you can use the deny-settings-excluded-actions parameter to exclude read actions from the deny settings.


Grant a user access to Azure resources using the Azure portal
Deny assignment policy for Service Fabric managed clusters
Deployment stacks - Protect managed resources against deletion


Do you know where can I find the syntax for the parameter --deny-settings-excluded-actions to deny read access ? On the documentation I provided, it only says that up to 200 actions are permitted

deny-settings-excluded-actions is used to add an exception beyond the denny-settings-mode. For example if you chose the deny-settings-mode "DenyDelete" you can still let users delete some ressources by specifying the precise ressource they can delete using seny-settings-excluded-actions

To do such thing, you have to create a role identical to the Contributor role and remove all permissions related to Bastion for this new role.
Then you will have to migrate contributors from old role to new role.
